# Javascript possivelmente atrapalhando query MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Recentemente eu comecei a trabalhar com bases de dados SQL e tenho tido problemas em armazenar colunas de tipo date nas minhas tabelas. Basicamente o que acontece quando tento armazenar uma variável no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, por exemplo `2016-12-23`, algo dá erado e o que entra na tabela é `0000-00-00`. Tentei mudar o tipo da variável de date para text e o valor armazenado foi `1981`, resultado da subtração `2016 - 12 - 23 = 1981`. Alguém por acaso já teve este problema ou sabe como resolvê-lo? Estou escrevendo meu projeto em node usando o módulo NPM MySQL.

```
var temp = "1994-03-09";
newStaticQuery = {
    sql: `INSERT INTO SaudeParamEstaticos (idPaciente, data, steps) VALUES (${id}, ${temp}, ${activity[property][0].value})`,
    timeout: 10000
}
connection.query(newStaticQuery, function(err, rows, fields) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Segue um exemplo mais simples do meu problema, seguindo o código abaixo, a data é inserida corretamente na tabela porém ao tentar colocá-la em uma variável temporária como no caso acima o problema acontece.

```
newStaticQuery = {
    sql: `INSERT INTO SaudeParamEstaticos (idPaciente, data, steps) VALUES (${id}, '1994-03-09', ${activity[property][0].value})`,
    timeout: 10000
}
connection.query(newStaticQuery, function(err, rows, fields) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Seria alguma questão de sintaxe do javascript?

Comment: Acabei de ler o Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas do stackoverflow e queria agradecer aos comentários construtivos à minha pergunta que é a minha primeira neste site bem como a paciência com todas as "atrocidades" que cometi na minha inocência de iniciante. Obrigado comunidade stackoverflow pela ausência de negatividade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria  o caso de acrescentar as aspas no template da *query* também:

```
sql: `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (VALUES (${id}, '${temp}', ${activity[property][0].value})`
                                             ^-aspas-^
```

Como é só uma substituição de valores, se passar sem as aspas é gerado algo assim...

```
VALUES (1, 1994-03-09, 489)
```

...em vez de gerar assim:

```
VALUES (1, '1994-03-09', 489)
```

e realmente, sem as aspas, o MySQL tratará numericamente da informação, calculando o valor, como você já havia percebido com os testes.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado @Bacco, um feliz natal!

Comment: Igualmente pra você, familiares e amigos. (e pro pessoal todo do site ;) )